# Which polynomial satisfy $f(a)=b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let us consider $a=c \cdot p^{\frac{p^3+1}{p^3(p^5-1)}}$ and $b= p^{\frac{p^3+1}{(p^5-1)}}$.

I want to find a polynomial such that $f(a)=b$.

---

Let $x=c \cdot p^{\frac{p^3+1}{p^3(p^5-1)}} \\ \Rightarrow x^{p^3(p^5-1)}=c^{p^3(p^5-1)} \cdot p^{p^3+1} \\ \Rightarrow x^{p^3}=c^{p^3} \cdot p^{\frac{p^3+1}{p^5-1}} \\ \Rightarrow x^{p^3}=c^{p^3}b \\ \Rightarrow c^{-p^3} x^{p^3}=b \\
\Rightarrow c^{-p^3}a^{p^3}=b.$

So I think $f(x)=c^{-p^3}x^{p^3}$ is the required polynomial.

Comment: Why not just a constant polynomial $f(x) = b$? Presumably that's not what you intend but it satisfies your criterion.

Comment: @RamanujanXV $b=f(a)=1$ if $f(x)=1$.

Comment: @Gary Ohk I understood.

Comment: There is an infinite number of polynomials that satisfy such an identity. So, you'll need some extra constraint to make the solution unique. In your case, that would a polynomial that consists of a single monomial. In this case, you can check whether your solution is correct by substituting $x$ by $a$ in $f(x)$ and verifying whether $f(a)=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose any polynomial $f(x)$ and define $c:=f(a)$. Then, $g(x):=f(x)-c+b$ satisfies $f(a)=b$.

For instance, if you take $f(x)=0$, you get $g(x)=b$.

If you take $f(x)=x$, you get $g(x)=x-a+b$.

If you require that the polynomial has a constant term of $0$, then your given polynomial works. Perhaps an easier calculation is to see that $a=c\times  b^{-p^3}$, so $b=\left (\frac{a}{c}\right )^{p^3}$, so we want $g(x)=\left (\frac{x}{c}\right )^{p^3}=c^{-p^3}x^{p^3}$.

Comment: It is also possible to define a polynomial $f(x)=h(x)*b/h(a)$ assuming that $h(a)\ne0$. Then, we will have that $f(a)=b$.